# Is there a way in MySQL to implicitly create a primary key for a table?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, when CREATE TABLE, is there a way for MySQL to implicitly create a column (i.e. a column not explicitly declared in CREATE TABLE command) as the primary key of the table?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Why would that be a thing?

Comment: I remeber I saw it somewhere, but I didn't remember the details. I am not sure if I mix it with something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the PRIMARY KEY needs to be defined on the table.

You may be thinking about [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), which applies to InnoDB engine:

> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB
>   internally generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on
>   a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by
>   the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is
>   a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted.
>   Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion
>   order.

Below is an example that shows this index's creation for a table with no PRIMARY KEY and no UNIQUE column.

```
# Create the table
create table test.check_table (id int, description varchar(10)) ENGINE = INNODB;

# Verify that there is no primary or unique column
desc test.check_table;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


# Insert some values
insert into test.check_table values(1, 'value-1');
insert into test.check_table values(2, 'value-2');
insert into test.check_table values(null, 'value-3');
insert into test.check_table values(4, null);
insert into test.check_table values(1, 'value-1');


# Verify table
select * from test.check_table;
+------+-------------+
| id   | description |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | value-1     |
|    2 | value-2     |
| NULL | value-3     |
|    4 | NULL        |
|    1 | value-1     |
+------+-------------+


# Verify that the GEN_CLUST_INDEX index is auto-created.
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_INDEX_STATS where TABLE_SCHEMA='test' and TABLE_NAME = 'check_table';
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| table_schema | table_name  | index_name      | fields | rows_per_key | index_total_pages | index_leaf_pages |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| test         | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX |      1 | 5            |                 1 |                1 |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+

# Duplicate rows are still allowed (Primary Key constraints not enforced)

insert into test.check_table values(1, 'value-1');

select * from test.check_table;
+------+-------------+
| id   | description |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | value-1     |
|    2 | value-2     |
| NULL | value-3     |
|    4 | NULL        |
|    1 | value-1     |
|    5 | value-5     |
|    1 | value-1     |
+------+-------------+
```

To contrast, a table with a PRIMARY KEY specified creates an index with name PRIMARY.

```
# Create another table
create table test.check_table_2 (id int, description varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;

# Verify primary key column
desc check_table_2;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| description | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

# Verify index
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_INDEX_STATS where TABLE_SCHEMA='test' and TABLE_NAME = 'check_table_2';
+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| table_schema | table_name    | index_name | fields | rows_per_key | index_total_pages | index_leaf_pages |
+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+
| test         | check_table_2 | PRIMARY    |      1 | 0            |                 1 |                1 |
+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+

# Primary key is enforced
insert into check_table_2 values(1,'value-1');
OK

insert into check_table_2 values(1,'value-1');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Thanks. But `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_INDEX_STATS where TABLE_SCHEMA='test' and TABLE_NAME = 'check_table';` doesn't output anything. It is supposed to verify that the GEN_CLUST_INDEX index is auto-created.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271907/how-can-we-verify-an-internal-index-is-created-for-a-relation  Thanks.

Comment: Seems related to MySQL version change. These following query will show the GEN_CLUST_INDEX entries for v8.0.11. `select * from mysql.innodb_index_stats where database_name='test' and table_name = 'check_table';`

Comment: Added an answer to the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271907/how-can-we-verify-an-internal-index-is-created-for-a-relation with results from running on MySQL v8.0.11.