# How can we verify an internal index is created for a relation?

Tags: mysql

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181742/3284469

> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB
>   internally generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on
>   a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by
>   the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is
>   a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted.
>   Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion
>   order.

My mysql version is:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

I followed the commands there to verify the internal index is created, but the last command doesn't show any index has been created. Why is that? Thanks.

Note that I changed the last command a little bit, because the original command gives me `Unknown table 'INNODB_INDEX_STATS' in information_schema` error.

```
# Create the table
create table test.check_table (id int, description varchar(10)) ENGINE = INNODB;

# Verify that there is no primary or unique column
desc test.check_table;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


# Insert some values
insert into test.check_table values(1, 'value-1');
insert into test.check_table values(2, 'value-2');
insert into test.check_table values(null, 'value-3');
insert into test.check_table values(4, null);
insert into test.check_table values(1, 'value-1');


# Verify table
select * from test.check_table;
+------+-------------+
| id   | description |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | value-1     |
|    2 | value-2     |
| NULL | value-3     |
|    4 | NULL        |
|    1 | value-1     |
+------+-------------+


# Verify that the GEN_CLUST_INDEX index is auto-created.
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_INDEX_STATS where TABLE_SCHEMA='test' and TABLE_NAME = 'check_table';

ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'INNODB_INDEX_STATS' in information_schema


SELECT DISTINCT     TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME ,    INDEX_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME='check_table';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all versions of MySQL that I've been able to find, the `INNODB_INDEX_STATS` table is located in the `mysql` database, not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. This appears to be an error in the post you're referencing.

```
mysql> select * from mysql.innodb_index_stats where table_name = 'check_table';
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| database_name | table_name  | index_name      | last_update         | stat_name    | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description                  |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 11:34:01 | n_diff_pfx01 |          5 |           1 | DB_ROW_ID                         |
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 11:34:01 | n_leaf_pages |          1 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 11:34:01 | size         |          1 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
```

This index isn't a "real" index from the perspective of SQL (it doesn't appear in the output of `DESCRIBE`, and can't be modified or dropped), so it isn't shown in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS`.

Answer (score 0):

For version 8.0.11, the table `innodb_index_stats` is located in `mysql` schema in lieu of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Following the commands, the last query gives result as below:

```
mysql> select VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.11    |
+-----------+

mysql> select * from mysql.innodb_index_stats where database_name='test' and table_name = 'check_table';
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| database_name | table_name  | index_name      | last_update         | stat_name    | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description                  |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 18:57:45 | n_diff_pfx01 |          5 |           1 | DB_ROW_ID                         |
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 18:57:45 | n_leaf_pages |          1 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| test          | check_table | GEN_CLUST_INDEX | 2018-07-10 18:57:45 | size         |          1 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Also, the post referenced in the question creates a second table with a primary key specified. The index verification for that query gives:

```
mysql> create table test.check_table_2 (id int, description varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;

mysql> desc check_table_2;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> select * from mysql.innodb_index_stats where database_name='test' and table_name = 'check_table_2';
+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| database_name | table_name    | index_name | last_update         | stat_name    | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description                  |
+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| test          | check_table_2 | PRIMARY    | 2018-07-10 19:00:39 | n_diff_pfx01 |          0 |           1 | id                                |
| test          | check_table_2 | PRIMARY    | 2018-07-10 19:00:39 | n_leaf_pages |          1 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| test          | check_table_2 | PRIMARY    | 2018-07-10 19:00:39 | size         |          1 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
```